# Compiling Ekiga from Source

Tags: ekiga

I'm compiling Ekiga from source. Apparently I have installed all the necessary dependencies because I don't get any errors when running `./configure`. There is one feature that I can't seem to enable however. The output from `./configure` shows `mDNS/DNS-SD support  :  disabled` Is there a missing dependency that I should install to enable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start configure with the AVAHI support, like this.

```
./configure --enable-avahi
```

This is what I got from the configure script.

```
--enable-avahi          enable mDNS support (default is disabled)
```

But, I suppose, this will not break the installation. You might miss the avahi after installation. Honestly, I don't even know what avahi is.

Comment: Excellent! And more important than just finding the solution to my problem you have shown me where I should look when I have a similar problem (i.e. the configure script). When I have enough reputation to upvote your answer, I will.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at ekiga's build dependencies on [it's packages.ubuntu.com source package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/quantal/ekiga).

From your commandline, you can install build dependencies automatically by using `sudo apt-get build-dep ekiga`.

Comment: hmm... I just now did a `sudo apt-get install <package-name>` for each of the mentioned packages (in your link) and although I didn't yet have liblaunchpad-integration-dev it still didn't enable the above mentioned feature. I wonder if that means it perhaps isn't a dependency issue? I guess there is also the possibility that the dependencies for the Ubuntu version don't include a certain dependency needed for the latest 4.0.1 version which I'm compiling.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, didn't read carefully enough. Is `sudo apt-get build-dep ekiga` the same as `sudo apt-get install`ing each of the dependencies in that list?